# VMRC full screen and without password prompt?

Tags: windows-10, vmware, thin-client

I am attempting to have a HP t430 thin client with Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC use VMRC into a VM on an ESXI server on startup.  I want it to 1) be full screen 2) hide or minimize the VMRC toolbar and 3) not ask for a user and password.

Currently I have a shortcut with the target as
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\vmrc.exe" "vmrc://192.168.44.224/?moid=3"`
And I set the shortcut to Run Maximized.

However, I always get asked the credentials for the esxi server, even if I click on `Remember Crednetials` during the VMRC bootup - the next time those fields are populated but I still have to click ok.  Then I still have to click the `Enter Full Screen Mode` from within the VMRC window toolbar to really make it full screen.

I found another post on on the vmware forum [here](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Windows-Discussions/Can-vmrc-exe-command-line-launch-all-the-way-into-a-VM-auto/td-p/506535) with the same exact problem but there wasn't a solution that was posted.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: vmrc doesn't have the option to pass credentials directly, but powerCLI can connect as the current user: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Remote-Console/VMRC-Shortcut/m-p/1415558#2597189. like `Connect-ViServer 'servername'; Get-VM 'VM-name' | Open-VMConsoleWindow`. Though to get it to always run fullscreen you might need to have it dump the single-use vmrc url with `-UrlOnly` and run `vmrc.exe -X [rest of url...]`

Answer (score 0):

The `-X` command-line option will start VMs in full-screen mode.

Additionally, there are hidden command-line options that you can use instead of the VMRC URL to specify credentials:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\vmrc.exe" ^
  -X ^
  --user YOUR_USERNAME ^
  --password YOUR_PASSWORD ^
  --host 192.168.44.224 ^
  --moid 3
```

**Be aware that passing a password via the command-line is insecure since the command-line for a process is visible to other processes.**

If you want the VM to run full-screen all the time with no UI, also consider running `vmware-kvm.exe` instead `vmrc.exe`, which supports the same command-line arguments. (Disclosure: I wrote vmware-kvm.)

(VMRC also has a hidden `--password-stdin` command-line option too that I think is supposed to be able to read the password from stdin (redirected from a pipe or file), but I don't remember how it's supposed work, if it does still work at all.)